# How to resolve the JNI Warning?

Tags: android, html, java-native-interface, nullpointerexception

I have a hybrid application in Android which involves native functions as well :

HTML 5 with javascript :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="menus.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery-ui-1.8.10.custom.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function openCamera1(){
            camera.startCameraActivity1();
            var path1=camera.getImagePath1();
            alert(path1);
            document.getElementById("image1").src=path1;
        }
        function openCamera2(){
            camera.startCameraActivity2();
            var path2=camera.getImagePath2();
            alert(path2);
            document.getElementById("image2").src=path2;
        }
        function show_confirm()   {
            var r=confirm("Do you wish to use the existing Details?");
            if (r==true)
            {
                alert("You pressed OK!"); 
            }   else     {
                alert("You pressed Cancel!");
            }
        }
```

in  html :

```
&lt;input type="button" onclick="show_confirm()" value="Register Cliam" /&gt;
```

in java : (android native):

```
public String getDetails(){  
    System.out.println("iiiiiiiiiiiiiiii");  
    String a=dh.hello();  
    System.out.println("aaaaaaaaaaaa " + a);
    return a;
}
```

Data helper class :

```
public String hello(){  
    return "Hello";  
}
```

And Exception i am facing :

```
    12-19 09:19:57.894: WARN/dalvikvm(718): JNI WARNING: JNI method called with exception raised  
    12-19 09:19:57.894: WARN/dalvikvm(718): in Landroid/webkit/WebViewCore;.nativeTouchUp (IIIII)V (NewGlobalRef)  
    12-19 09:19:57.894: WARN/dalvikvm(718): Pending exception is:  
    12-19 09:19:57.894: INFO/dalvikvm(718): Ljava/lang/NullPointerException;:  
    12-19 09:19:57.894: INFO/dalvikvm(718): at com.test.hybrid.aviva.OpenCamera.getDetails(OpenCamera.java:179)  
    12-19 09:19:57.894: INFO/dalvikvm(718):     at android.webkit.WebViewCore.nativeTouchUp(Native Method)  
    12-19 09:19:57.894: INFO/dalvikvm(718):     at android.webkit.WebViewCore.access$3400(WebViewCore.java:48)  
    12-19 09:19:57.905: INFO/dalvikvm(718):     at android.webkit.WebViewCore$EventHub$1.handleMessage(WebViewCore.java:1094)  
    12-19 09:19:57.925: INFO/dalvikvm(718):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)  
    12-19 09:19:57.925: INFO/dalvikvm(718):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)  
    12-19 09:19:57.925: INFO/dalvikvm(718):     at android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:611)  
    12-19 09:19:57.925: INFO/dalvikvm(718):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)  
    12-19 09:19:57.925: INFO/dalvikvm(718): "WebViewCoreThread" prio=5 tid=15 NATIVE  
    12-19 09:19:57.934: INFO/dalvikvm(718):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 s=N obj=0x44c13848 self=0x139858  
    12-19 09:19:57.934: INFO/dalvikvm(718):   | sysTid=725 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=default handle=1284464  
    12-19 09:19:57.934: INFO/dalvikvm(718):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore.nativeTouchUp(Native Method)  
    12-19 09:19:57.934: INFO/dalvikvm(718):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore.nativeTouchUp(Native Method)
    12-19 09:19:57.934: INFO/dalvikvm(718):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore.access$3400(WebViewCore.java:48)  
    12-19 09:19:57.934: INFO/dalvikvm(718):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore$EventHub$1.handleMessage(WebViewCore.java:1094)
    12-19 09:19:57.934: INFO/dalvikvm(718):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)  
    12-19 09:19:57.934: INFO/dalvikvm(718):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)  
    12-19 09:19:57.955: INFO/dalvikvm(718):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:611)   
    12-19 09:19:57.955: INFO/dalvikvm(718):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)  
    12-19 09:19:57.955: ERROR/dalvikvm(718): VM aborting
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highly suspect

```
String a=dh.hello();
```

dh is null.